# Codename One Drag & Drop get target

Tags: drag-and-drop, codenameone, droptarget

I have an application with some labels and containers. I want to drag the labels into the containers and assert that the containers receive a specific label. (A game for kids [starting with my 6-year-old daughter, who is learning to read], where the next level can be accessed after the labels are arranged in a specific order to form words or phrases.)

For the moment, I am using something like this :

```
label_1.addDropListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                

            String string = label_1.getParent().toString();

}
```

But this approach only gets the value of the container where the label has been before, and not the value of the drop target.

I could get the current position by a new button, but I'd rather solve this through the drag & drop operation.

There seems to a draggingOver method (like in JavaFX), but I can't figure out a way to use it.

Any kind hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is probably to subclass `Container` where you can override the drag over. In that case you will also know the container instance.

In the case of the listener you would need one listener per container and that way you could have the container reference.

Comment: Thank you, Shai, would you happen to have a snippet?

Comment: Closest thing I can find is the actual code to implement drop in `Container` itself: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/575115a327bfec454900049b5416020e32352b67/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Container.java#L2557-L2582